# Disconnect Output while on Charging

Tags: mosfet, batteries, power-electronics, battery-charging, tp4056

I am trying to disconnect the power supply to the load while the battery is charging, I tried some circuits, but none of them work:

[image: IRLML6402]
[image: DMP1045U]
[image: SI2301]

I am not from an electronics background, can someone please help me, would really appreciate that.

Comment: Can you please explain more about what you want to do?

Comment: @GeorgeGuo I want to disconnect the power supply to the load connected to the battery when charger is connected